# Not able to render a popup in rails 3.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1, modal-dialog

I want to render a popup if a link is clicked.

I have got two actions home and test inside pages controller:-

In the pages/home.html.erb view if I do

```
<div id="myModal" class= "reveal-modal">
  <h1> Modal Window</h1>
  <p> I am inside a modal</p>
</div>

<div>
  <%=link_to "Modal", test_url,:class=> "buttonForModal"%>
</div>
```

and in pages.js file

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     $('.buttonForModal').click(function(e) {
          e.preventDefault();
      $('#myModal').reveal();
     });
});
```

This works fine, giving me a nice popup window.

However if I place this

```
<div id="myModal" class= "reveal-modal">
      <h1> Modal Window</h1>
      <p> I am inside a modal</p>
</div>
```

in pages/test.html.erb view and this in pages/home.html.erb

```
<div>
      <%=link_to "Modal", test_url,:class=> "buttonForModal"%>
</div>
```

I do not get any popup nor anything is rendered, what could be the issue? do I need to explicitly mention controller and action name?

I was testing the above code so that I could put the devise login in a popup but same issues with that as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Showing a modal popup is done by javascript. The javascript is executed in the browser. The javascript code you show actually expects the modal to be present in the HTML.

So what you need to do is render the view you want as a popup inside your view.

So as for your example, in your `pages/show.html.erb` you should write:

```
<div>
  <%=link_to "Modal", test_url,:class=> "buttonForModal" %>
</div>

= render :partial => 'pages/test'
```

And inside the file `pages/_test.html.erb` (note the extra underscore!) you put your modal-view.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

the "#myModal" must be on the same page as the ".buttonForModal" and the javascript...

Right now it seems like the "#myModal" is not on the same page as the ".buttonForModal", which means jquery cant find the "#myModal" div when the button is clicked...

Comment: In that case how is it going to work with devise? As I have got my signup and login button in the application/layout where as the devise views are in devise/views folder

Comment: There are many ways to do that, all you have to do is to make sure your code is on the same page